# How do these streamers toggle between game and justin.tv so easily?

Tags: starcraft-2

I see all these streamers (e.g. EGIdrA, FXOShelth, etc) switching out of SC2 and onto their music player or justin.tv channel with little to no delay.  When using alt+tab there's quite a few delayed seconds before I'm able to interact with the new focus in any way.  Is it some windows 7 shortcut, or some fancy keyboard with a binded button to desktop?

Comment: A lot of RAM helps, I can switch to another application from SC2 on a system with 12GB of RAM almost instantly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are playing Starcraft 2 in full screen windowed mode. This allows for much quicker swapping, but only if your system can handle it.  Full screen windowed mode is a little more system intensive than just full screen mode.